# In question lists, some of the question body previews wrap strangely

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, question-summary

I just noticed a question which appears slightly odd in Firefox 3.5 - "them." is the only text on the second line, so it appears in a rather odd location. (I expect it would wrap to be under the word "For" like all other questions.)

Using IE6, however, this displays correctly.

Anyone else see (or not see) this?

<sub>Full browser details: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1) Gecko/20090624 Firefox/3.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not really browser specific; I can repro it in IE8 and Chrome as well.

I think it's just a side effect of float left (tags) and float right (user info), but I'll have to check.