# Layout quirk on questions page - Preview/summary displacement

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, question-summary, markdown-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange formatting on questions page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4545/strange-formatting-on-questions-page)

Take a look at the following screenshot of a question snippet:

http://media.dominicrodger.com/quirk.jpg

The layout quirk is that the end of the question summary/preview ends up on a new line all by itself and floating to the right.

Occurs in Chrome 3.0, Firefox 3.5, IE 8 (note that the question referenced in the above image has been edited, which means the bug doesn't show up if you look for that question).

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I'm not seeing an image...

Comment: Shoot it, or it never happened!

Comment: Oh, weird - I can see it. I'll try hosting it elsewhere.

Comment: Is that any better?

Comment: Image is at http://media.dominicrodger.com/quirk.jpg, if you can't see it inline.

Answer (score 2):

Replicated on Windows 7, Firefox 3.5.4, here on Meta this morning. Seems to be an issue when the summary text is within a certain # of characters past overflowing a line?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not true for FireFox 3.5.4:

[alt text http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/9190/nottrueff.png](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/9190/nottrueff.png)

Comment: Wonder if that's because the question text has been changed slightly?

Comment: You could ask the same question here on Meta in the sandbox to find out. Personally I'm too lazy to do that...