# Excerpts one word longer than one line float the one word to the right instead of the left

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, question-lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In question lists, some of the question body previews wrap strangely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4545/strange-formatting-on-questions-page)

Notice this question excerpt as displayed through [newest questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest):

[screenshot http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/7252/longwayfromhomed.jpg](http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/7252/longwayfromhomed.jpg)

I'd think it belongs over on the left.

Using: Win XP Firefox 3.5
No-Repro: iPad, XP IE7

Comment: Browser info required. I cannot duplicate on Chrome 5.0.375.70; it appears to have been edited, however, and I can't see the original.

Comment: Replicated on IE8 on XP

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 6.0.408.1 dev.

Comment: @Randolpho: Make sure you check the question in the right context (link edited into this question's text).

Comment: @Gnome: ahh, now I see it. Good edit.

Comment: @Jon Seigel: Thanks.  I'm gonna have to get better at searching.

Comment: @Jason: That one wasn't easy to find. I'm going to edit so it's more searchable.

Comment: @jon well, it doesn't help that *someone* gave this a "CLEVER" title, either, now does it?

Comment: @Jeff: I'm getting reprimanded already?  This doesn't bode well...

Comment: @Jeff:  It seems (XP IE7 FF3.5) that if you widen `.excerpt .tags` out to close the gap between the `tags` div and the `started` div the issue goes away.  I don't see any other effects, but that isn't a guarantee it's a total fix...